# Disable an item in selectinput dropdown

Tags: shiny

How do I disable an item in a `selectInput()` dropdown menu?

For example;

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(selectInput("id1","Select",choices=c("A","B","C")))
server <- function(input, output) {}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Say, for whatever reason, option **C** cannot be selected due to some logic. I would like the user to be able to see all the options, but have option **C** disabled/unselectable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using `pickerInput` from package [shinyWidgets](https://github.com/dreamRs/shinyWidgets) :

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
ui <- fluidPage(
  pickerInput(
    inputId = "id1",
    label = "Select :",
    choices = c("A", "B", "C"),
    multiple = FALSE,
    choicesOpt = list(
      disabled = c("A", "B", "C") %in% c("C")
    )
  ),
  verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "result")
)
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$result <- renderPrint(input$id1)
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

That's also possible to do that from the server, see example in `?updatePickerInput`

Comment: What if I want to disable the current selection after it has been selected? So that the individual cannot select it again? When I try that I get an error... which I think is due to the fact that a lot of other elements on the app are dependent on the current selection. Does that make sense?

Answer (score -1):

I believe it can't be done with standard shiny. You can try to apply some css/js magic if you know it (e.g., turn not selectable items to red color and give a message to user if they chose it anyways, or maybe you can directly disable clicking on them with js/css, not sure, see `sendCustomMessage()`).

Another option would be to use `updateSelectInput()` to discard not needed items from the dropdown when you need it.

**update:**

I did a quick search on it -- as I can see it is doable with html option `disabled`, e.g.

```
<select>
  <option value="volvo" disabled>Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="vw">VW</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

All you need to do is to generate shiny's `selectInput` on the server (probably with `renderUI()`) and add that `disabled` option to the elements you need to disable